# Android P Restrictions on non-SDK interfaces - dark greylist vs blacklist

Tags: android, reflection, android-9.0-pie, android-p-developer-preview

Developer Preview 3 came out today and I've noticed some changes related to non-SDK interfaces:

Accessing the following API produces different logs on DP2 and DP3

```
Class<?> androidIdClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
Integer search_close_btn = getFieldValue(androidIdClass, null, "search_close_btn");
```

DP2: 
`Accessing hidden field Lcom/android/internal/R$id;->search_close_btn:I (blacklist, reflection)`

Result: NoSuchFieldException, unable to access the field

DP3: `Accessing hidden field Lcom/android/internal/R$id;->search_close_btn:I (dark greylist, reflection)`

Result: the field is accessible

Can please someone explain why this field become available in DP3 and what is difference between **dark greylist** and **blacklist** ?

Comment: Mishaal Rahman of XDA [pointed out](https://twitter.com/MishaalRahman/status/1004859447401959426) that [this podcast](https://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/2018/04/episode-89-upon-reflection.html) covers the difference in the API lists. In terms of why there was a change, my guess is that somebody filed an issue saying that they needed it, and so they downgraded the penalty. If I understand correctly, this field is still at risk of no longer being accessible in the future.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for the comment and the link to podcast. According to the info in podcast the blacklist is what they think no one is using so they added that private API there so none can start using it. I assume that DP2 has shown that the APIs from blacklist are used and they moved those APIs back to dark greylist list

Answer (score 3):

Can please someone explain why this field become available in DP3?

- Google is continuously blocking non-SDK calls. But they have also opened the forum for developers where issues regarding these can be reported. 
  So to answer your question someone might have created a ticket regarding this which Google might have thought to rollback. Make sense?

what is the difference between dark greylist and blacklist?

- Blacklist are calls which are not going to work irrespective of what API level your application is going to target.
- Dark greylist are calls which won't work if and only if your application is targeting API level 28 else they would work normally.

Comment: What about greylist-max-p? What happens when you target API level 28 and run Android 10? Do the calls work because the target API level is equal to the greylist-max-p or fail because the Android version is higher? I'm really confused about this.